# FFMpeg How to use multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, ffmpeg

I want to decode H264 by ffmpeg, BUT finally I found the decode function only used one cpu core

[system monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1qqk.png)

env: Ubuntu 14.04 FFMpeg 3.2.4 CPU i7-7500U

---

So, I search ffmpeg multithreading and decide using all cpu cores for decoding.
I set AVCodecContext as this:

```
//Init works
//codecId=AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
avcodec_register_all();
pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(codecId);
if (!pCodec)
{
    printf("Codec not found\n");
    return -1;
}
pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
if (!pCodecCtx)
{
    printf("Could not allocate video codec context\n");
    return -1;
}

pCodecParserCtx=av_parser_init(codecId);
if (!pCodecParserCtx)
{
    printf("Could not allocate video parser context\n");
    return -1;
}
pCodecCtx->thread_count = 4;
pCodecCtx->thread_type = FF_THREAD_FRAME;

pCodec->capabilities &= CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED;
pCodecCtx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;

if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0)
{
    printf("Could not open codec\n");
    return -1;
}
av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET);
av_init_packet(&packet);
```

---

```
//parse and decode
//after av_parser_parse2, the packet has a complete frame data
//in decode function, I just call avcodec_decode_video2 and do some frame copy work
while (cur_size>0)
{
    int len = av_parser_parse2(
                  pCodecParserCtx, pCodecCtx,
                  &packet.data, &packet.size,
                  cur_ptr, cur_size,
                  AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE);

    cur_ptr += len;
    cur_size -= len;
    if(GetPacketSize()==0)
        continue;

    AVFrame *pFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    int ret = Decode(pFrame);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (ret)
    {
      //some works
    }
}
```

But nothing different with before.
How can I use multithreading in FFMpeg? Any advise?

Comment: you will need to show more code. How do you measure how many cores are used? How do you decode frames? What version of FFmpeg? How did you allocate pCodecParserCtx?

Comment: Recv rtp stream use boost asio first, then decode by ffmpeg, show with opengl. I have added some parse and decode code. I just watch system monitor to measure cores usages, if I just decode video and no display, only one core work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pCodec->capabilities &= CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED;

And that's your bug. Please remove this line. The return value of `avcodec_find_decoder()` should for all practical intents and purposes be considered const.

Specifically, this statement removes the [`AV_CODEC_CAP_FRAME_THREADS`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#gae21e6310b40920cd61f54e9c320d8e6c) flag from the codec's capabilities, thus effectively disabling frame-multithreading in the rest of the code.